# Что сделать с числом 0x1122, чтобы получить его последние 2 цифры?

Tags: pascal

Что сделать с числом 0x1122, чтобы получить его последние 2 цифры?

Comment: На сколько я помню, в паскале используется `$`, а не `0x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имеются в виду именно две последние цифры в шестнадцатеричном представлении, то надо просто наложить маску $FF:

```
Z := $1122 AND $FF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо взять остаток от деления на 0x100 (256)

Answer (score 0):

```
while num>=256 do num:=num-256;
```

не?
А вообще, правильней будет логическое умножение на **FF**. Не помню уже, есть ли в паскале такое.

Пришла в голову ещё одна больная идея:

```
num := num - (num shr 8) shl 8;
```

Comment: В принципе, работает, только вам придётся потом переводить обратно в **HEX**

Comment: Да в паскале есть логическое "или".

    num := num and $ff;//называется сие маскированием

Это самый лучший из ваших ответов.

Comment: Логическое **"и"**, **"или"** - это логическое сложение :)